# (Mysql) How to mark different WHERE OR rows?

Tags: sql, mysql, where-clause

For example i have requested:

```
WHERE (friend_id=? OR client_id=?)
```

How do i know which row meets friend_id condition and which meets client_id condition?

Is it possible to mark/flag rows depending of meeting condition somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT friend_id=? FROM yourtable WHERE (friend_id=? OR client_id=?);
```

You will get a true if the friend_id clause matches:
Or even:

```
SELECT friend_id=?, client_id=? FROM yourtable WHERE (friend_id=? OR client_id=?);
```

To get both matches. In this way you can see if one or both matches.

Comment: Thanks mate, i like your example. :)

That's what i got now:

SELECT friend_id=17 AS receiver, client_id=17 AS sender FROM relationships WHERE (friend_id=17 OR client_id=17);

Answer (score 1):

### Use CASE operator

If knowing which row was hit because by any condition **you can of course add this data** to your result columns using `case` operators. The only downside is that your variables in your prepared statement (if that's what you're having here) are going to be doubled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION.

For example:

```
SELECT name, 1

FROM friends

WHERE friend_id=?

UNION

SELECT name, 0

FROM friends

WHERE client_id=?
```

Then when receiving data, you can check for that flag

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,
       'Friend' AS Source
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE friend_id = ?
UNION
SELECT *,
       'Client' AS Source
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE client_id = ?
```

But you'll have an issue if your entry is both friend and client. What do you want to happen in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF(), but then you have to bind one of id twice:

```
SELECT IF(friend_id=?, 'friend', 'client') AS type
FROM table
WHERE (friend_id=? OR client_id=?)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add flags to the query:

```
SELECT *, IF((friend_id=$friend_id), 1, 0) AS friend_matched, IF((client_id=$client_id), 1, 0) AS client_matched FROM table WHERE (friend_id=? OR client_id=?)
```